# How to convert int type data in hive to string type in scala without scientific notation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

How to convert int type data in hive to string type in **scala** without scientific notation？
I have some data in hive, it's presenting in Int type, I would like to transfer it to String type and store the data by a spark job as parquet file.

| name: String | birth_date: Int |
| --- | --- |
| Vincent | 20090502 |
| Lauren | 20170509 |

I do this step:

```
df.withColumn("birth_date", col("birth_date").cast("String"))
```

then I'm getting output with scientific notation like 2E+07, which is the value for 20190502.

How can I get the output data without scientific notation?

Comment: When I test with my Spark, your code worked like intended, there isn't anything like 2E+07. Still you could try [format_number function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.format_number.html)

Comment: I also tried on my Spark instance and it works as expected (no scientfic notation).
Moreover if you wanted to stored is a date, you can call to_date from org.apache.spark.sql.functions object